# Generate HTML from a plain text

Tags: c#, html, vb.net, richtextbox, rich-text-editor

I have a desktop application displaying text in a read only RichTextbox component.  Some words in the text needs to be highlighted depending on a text analyze that was previously executed.

Now I need to create a web version of this application.

I know there's a [couple of Rich Text Editors](http://www.queness.com/post/212/10-jquery-and-non-jquery-javascript-rich-text-editors) available but I would like to know if there's a library or a simple way to generate an properly tagged HTML string from a plain text and a list of word to highlight?

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a free extension to RichTextbox that do what you want:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12172/An-extended-RichTextBox-to-save-and-load-quot-HTML

Comment: Well, this component is really interesting.  However, my new project will be 100% web but if I set a reference to System.Windows.Form, then I'll be able to work with a RichTextbox without displaying it on a form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TinyMCE. This is free javascript based Reach Text Editor for the web.

[TinyMCE Reach Text Editor](http://www.tinymce.com/)

Comment: As mentioned in my question, I'm not looking for a Text editor component.